# How can I print variables inside function every 3 seconds using recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I wanna print variable inside function every 3 seconds using recursion (or loop)

so I've tried to

```js
function printVariables() {
  let num = 1;

  if (num > 4) {
    console.log(num);
    num = 1;
    } else {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
    }

  setInterval(printVariables, 3000);
};

//i've expected1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ···
//but it's only printed 2, 2, 2, 2, ···
```

How can I fix that as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a couple of changes to your code:

1. Your `i` is getting defined in every function execution, that is not what you want. It will never move to more than 1. So move it outside your function.
2. Now, in the code below innerPrintVariable has access to `i` because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). It is a concept where functions can access variables from their lexical scope.
3. You will notice that I have used var instead of let. Reason being, let is block scoped. And every iteration will redefine the`i` if it is block scoped and hence will always stay 1. `var` is not block scoped.

```
function printVariables() {
    var num = 1;

    function innerPrintVariables() {
        if (num > 4) {
            console.log(num);
            num = 1;
        } else {
            console.log(num);
            num++;
        }
    }

    setInterval(innerPrintVariables, 3000);
}

printVariables();
```

Comment: You've made this overly complicated, and this isn't the right way to do this. Please look at my answer. Also it looks like you just copy pated my answer to your own.

Comment: Both of us used the same source of code(the OPs) so it might look like that. But I enclosed it inside a function because OP also was not using any globals. I assumed that is what he wanted.

Comment: I don't know why this got negative vote. It demonstrate closure in javascript very well and the code works too.

Answer (score 0):

Always check the scope and access of your variables

```js
var num = 1;

function printVariables() {

  if (num > 4) {
    console.log(num);
    num = 1;
    } else {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
    }
};

setInterval(printVariables, 3000);
```

Comment: What if i don't want to use a global variable?
i don't wanna reuse variable so i've put variable into function

Comment: if you don't use a global variable then it has no way to keep track of the status. This is basics of scope mechanics

Answer (score 0):

I think its printing/ console logging 1, not 2. The reason for this being the `num` variable is declared inside `printVariables` function which has the local variable named `num` and this variable gets created on every execution/invokation of the function. And also `setInterval` is placed inside the `printVariables` function. As mentioned by [Kwright02 above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67964798/9437418) always beware of local and global variables.

**Suggetion:** Always have a clearInterval and clearTimeout whenever these API's are used, as this would start consuming memory when it goes unchecked.

Solution suggested by kwright is one of the correct solution, to have variables declared as a global variables and use them inside the function. This will also leave a possibility of other functions modifying the variable.

Other possibiltiy :

```js
let setIntervalID;

function printVariables(num = 1) {
    clearInterval(setIntervalID);

    if (num > 4) {
        console.log(num);
        num = 1;
    } else {
        console.log(num);
        num++;
    }

    setIntervalID = setInterval(printVariables, 3000, num);
};
printVariables();
```